# Derivative of max with respect to a variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I encountered $\max_a f(x, a)$ and I wonder how to compute the derivative with respect to x. Is it $\frac{\partial f(x, a)}{\partial x}$ ?

Comment: Assuming it is differentiable, the derivative isn't partial since the function is in one variable: $x$. So, the derivative, if it exists, would be $$\frac d{dx}\text{max}_a(f(x,a))$$

Comment: And if I had $max_a f(x, a, b)$, would it be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} max_a f(x, a, b)$?

Comment: Yes, it would indeed